# Execute commands over Telnet, logging to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, networking

I have made some code that will login to a device and send all your additional commands. It also logs the commands and the returned values to a file on the local system.

Hope somebody can tell me if the code is a little effective or how I can optimize it. I also have a question about the Sleep I think it's not so effective because some commands take longer then others. How can I resolve this can you let it sleep until a certain reply is given?

As I run the code with a other program which not give feedback other then failed. That is why the errors are redirected to a file.

```
#Modules imported when white they are used in the script
#
import sys, traceback, telnetlib, time
#
# When Using main function tracebacks (errors)
# Are not shown in the terminal/console but are logged to.
# C:/temp/errlog.txt also see bottom of script for code usage.
#
#TO RUN IT FROM CMD
#python Telnet_Program.py 192.168.10.2 23 cisco cisco enable cisco "conf t" "hostname R5" end "wr mem" "" "show users" "show ip int brief"
#
path_of_script = sys.argv[0]
host_address = sys.argv[1]
port = sys.argv[2]
termlen = sys.argv.insert(7, "term len 0")
#
#Define globals
global newfiles
global tn
#
#open file for output. first open/close to empty file.
newfiles = open('C:/temp/my-test.txt', 'w')
newfiles.close()
newfiles = open('C:/temp/my-test.txt', 'a')
#
# #creaete new var for Telnet session.
tn = telnetlib.Telnet()
#tn.set_debuglevel(1)

def main():

    def telnet_Program(host_address, port):
        """
        Function for login and parsing commands to telnet session.
        Which utilize read_data_tn_session and write_data_to_file functions.
        The read_data_tn function will empty the buffer into a list which is writen to a file by the
        write_data_to_file function.
        """

        tn.open(str(host_address), int(port), 5)

        #Pars extra commands given through the Telnet interperter.
        #for x in args() use all extra values right of path/user/password:
        for x in sys.argv[3:]:
            #Sleep to receive input from Telnet session before reading

            #write_data_to_file()
            #Write variables to node. and wait before reading.
            tn.write(x.encode("ascii")+b"\r\n")
            write_data_to_file()

        #read last command and close connection to host.
        write_data_to_file()
        #pri_prefix_nr = result_pri_prefix_service_analyzelen[(result_pri_prefix_service_analyze)-2].split(' ')
        newfiles.close()
        tn.close()

#Call the def telnet_program)
    telnet_Program(host_address, port)

#while data in the loop read the output and write to file.


def read_data_tn_session():
    """
    While data in the read buffer loop and add to list lines_return. Then return the complete buffer as a list.
    In this case return the list to the write_data function.
    """
    while True:
        #Get the information from the buffer and split it on \r\n.
        line = tn.read_very_eager().decode().split("\r\n")
        #print(line)

        #Create empty variable for usage in for x in line loop.
        lines_return = []
        for x in line:
            #check if line received is not empty. Then add it to the lines_return list.
            if x:
                lines_return.append(x)
        return lines_return

def write_data_to_file():
    """
    If data in read/buffer from telnet session call read_data_tn_session.
    This will create a list which we then write to an file.
    """
    #
    #wait until receive buffer is filled with telnet information.
    time.sleep(0.5)
    #
    #use read_data loop to read the data from telnet session and create a list from it.
    lines = read_data_tn_session()
    #
    #print(lines)
    #
    if lines:
        #newfiles.write(lines.pop() + '\n')

        for x in lines:
            newfiles.write(x + '\n')

""""!!!!!!!!!!!!PART OF MAIN Def!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
!Let you log all errors generated by functions
!Within the main function.
!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
"""

if __name__=="__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except:
        print ("Trigger Exception, traceback info forward to log file.")
        traceback.print_exc(file=open("C:/temp/errlog.txt","w"))

        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're writing your own Python program rather than using, say, [`ciscocmd`](https://github.com/eczema/ciscocmd-cosi/blob/master/ciscocmd)?

Comment: I did know of the ciscocmd. I will have a look at it, thanks for that.
 
The main reason that I did not looked for an other program was that I wanted to learn python better. So I did learn a lot from building this script. But I'm still missing things. 

Such as how to make the program wait until the complete output is received and go on to the next command.

Comment: you may want to check PrettyGoodTerminal. It is designed exatly for what you are looking for and there are quite a few examples on its website, too.

Answer (score 1):

#### `argparse` / tuple unpacking

```
path_of_script = sys.argv[0]
host_address = sys.argv[1]
port = sys.argv[2]
termlen = sys.argv.insert(7, "term len 0")
```

Argparse is the standard way of dealing with command line arguments and it automatically generates information messages for the user, so it has extra convenience.

Instead of variable length arguments you could make one of them a list and loop through it.

If you are not yet ready to refactor like this, then you can use at least tuple unpacking (and slicing):

```
path_of_script, host_address, port = sys.argv[:3]
```

This is simpler, a, b, c are the first three elements in respective order.

#### File handling

```
#open file for output. first open/close to empty file.
newfiles = open('C:/temp/my-test.txt', 'w')
newfiles.close()
newfiles = open('C:/temp/my-test.txt', 'a')
```

You can use `with` to open files to have them close automatically.

Using `w` mode clears all content of the file, and you can still write to it, no need to open/close.

Anyway of a comment I would prefer a function `erase_file_content` for self-documenting code.

#### List comprehension

My favourite feature, it avoids so much boilerplate code:

```
    #Create empty variable for usage in for x in line loop.
    lines_return = []
    for x in line:
        #check if line received is not empty. Then add it to the lines_return list.
        if x:
            lines_return.append(x)
    return lines_return
```

Becomes:

```
return [l for l in lines if l]
```

(Please note that `line` should be renamed `lines` because it is a list of lines not a single line).

As you can see the core of the logic (discarding blank lines) is still there but without the waste of space and effort that there was before.

The comments are too specific, as we always say on this site **comment on the why, not on the how**, comments like `#Create empty variable for usage in for x in line loop.` are unnecessary redundancy.

#### Functions taking arguments

`def write_data_to_file():` should take a file object and some data as argument, passing arguments allows testing and re-use.

Comment: I cannot comment on syncronization / sleeping because I never really studied those concepts. And your code is pretty nicely structured and documented with docstrings, sometimes I feel like my review might sound a bit harsh but I do not want to be rude or let people down. Have a good coding :)